# Jquery Webcam Plugin

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using jQuery webcam to capture a photo of the client. I need to send it to the server just when the form is submitted (It's a form with information, and I need to have the photo attached to it).

I have everything working except the part of saving the image encoded with base64 to the database like blob.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pos = 0;
var ctx = null;
var cam = null;
var image = null;

jQuery("#webcam").webcam({

    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "/../../js/jscam_canvas_only.swf",

    onTick: function(remain) {

        if (0 == remain) {
            jQuery("#status").text("Sorria!");
        } else {
            jQuery("#status").text(remain + " segundo(s) restante(s)...");
        }
    },

    onSave: function(data) {

    var col = data.split(";");
    var img = image;

    for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
        var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
        img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
        img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
        img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
        img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
        pos+= 4;
    }

    if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240) {
        ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var save_image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        save_image = save_image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");  
        $('input[name=save_image]').val(save_image);
        pos = 0;
    }
},

    onCapture: function () {

        jQuery("#flash").css("display", "block");
        jQuery("#flash").fadeOut(100, function () {
            jQuery("#flash").css("opacity", 1);
        });
                jQuery("#canvas").show();
                webcam.save();
    },

    onLoad: function () {

        var cams = webcam.getCameraList();
        for(var i in cams) {
            jQuery("#cams").append("<li>" + cams[i] + "</li>");
        }
                jQuery("#canvas").hide();
    }
});

function getPageSize() {

    var xScroll, yScroll;

    if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {
        xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
        yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
    } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
        xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
    } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
        xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }

    var windowWidth, windowHeight;

    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        } else {
            windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
        }
        windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
        windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
        windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
    if(yScroll < windowHeight){
        pageHeight = windowHeight;
    } else {
        pageHeight = yScroll;
    }

    // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
    if(xScroll < windowWidth){
        pageWidth = xScroll;
    } else {
        pageWidth = windowWidth;
    }

    return [pageWidth, pageHeight];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    jQuery("body").append("<div id=\"flash\"></div>");

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 320, 240);
        }
        image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);
    }
    var pageSize = getPageSize();
    jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });

}, false);

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {

    var pageSize = getPageSize();
    jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });

}, false);
</script>
```

Then I have just a normal form that the customer has to fill it in, followed by this:

```
<div id="webcam">
</div>
<p style="width:250px;text-align:center; "><input type="button" value="Tirar Fotografia" onclick="webcam.capture(3);void(0);"/></p></td><td><p><canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas></p>
```

in php i have:

```
  $image=file_get_contents(base64_decode($_POST['save_image']));
```

Comment: perhaps you should describe exactly how it's not working, any error messages, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Worked with just  `$image=$_POST['save_image'];` in php:).
Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Dre, this is the OP answering his own question.